# pygtk issue - unable to create gdk.Color object

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gdk

I'm creating a simple application through glade, and I want to be able to set the color displayed in the color selection dialog. I found the set_current_color function, however, it requires a gdk.Color object.

Trying to import gtk.gdk.Color fails (actually, just importing gtk fails). Is there another method I can use to create a color object?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue of mixing GTK2 and GTK3. gi.repository.Gtk has the Color constructor.